# Do sections determine a smooth manifold structure on $E$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

This is a follow up question from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929801/why-are-e-f-and-e-ast-smooth-manifolds).

If I have $E = \bigsqcup_{p \in M}E_p$, where each $E_p$ is $k-$dimensional vector space, and for each $p \in M$ there is $U \ni p$ an open neighborhood and $s_1,\ldots,s_k\colon U \to E$ such that $\{s_i(p)\}$ span $E_p$ for each $p$, then does it follow that $E$ has a smooth manifold structure such that $(E,\pi,M)$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$, and with these sections and the projection $\pi :E \to M$ being all smooth?

I attempted to use lemma $5.5$ in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* as pointed in the previous answer. I only have to define bijections $\varphi\colon \pi^{-1}[U] \to U \times \Bbb R^k$ that are linear isomorphisms in each fiber, and check that they glue nicely. Certainly $\varphi\left(\lambda^i s_i(p)\right) = (p,(\lambda^i))$ is the way to go. Assume that we have done this construction for two open sets $U_\alpha$ and $U_\beta$, with sections $s_i^\alpha$ and $s_i^\beta$, and trivialization candidates $\varphi_\alpha$ and $\varphi_\beta$.  Write $s_j^\beta(p) = h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}(p)s_i^\alpha(p)$ for some convenient coefficients. We have $$\varphi_\alpha \circ \varphi_\beta^{-1}(p, (\lambda^i)) = \varphi_\alpha(\lambda^js_j^\beta(p))= \varphi_{\alpha}\left(\lambda^j  h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}(p)s_i^\alpha(p)\right) = (p, \lambda^j  h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}(p)).$$Since $h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}(p)$ works as a change of basis matrix, we have that $$g_{\alpha\beta}\colon U_\alpha\cap U_\beta \to {\rm GL}(k,\Bbb R)$$given by $g_{\alpha\beta}(p)((\lambda^i)) = h^i_{\hspace{.5em}j}(p)\lambda^j$ really is non-singular. But I can't check that these $g_{\alpha\beta}$ are smooth on $p$, so I can apply lemma $5.5$. I know that if I can check that each $h^i_{\hspace{.5em}j}$ depends smoothly on $p$ I'm done, because matrix entries are global coordinates in ${\rm GL}(k,\Bbb R)$. Please help me.

Comment: Your question, as stated in your 2nd paragraph, puts no requirement on the smooth manifold structure apart from the one that it turns E into a vector bundle, so the answer is trivially yes: your set E can be turned into a trivial $k$-dimensional bundle over $M$, and that extra condition you mention is completely irrelevant in this.

Comment: How can I fix that then? The whole point of this is to use sections instead of trivializations to induce the structure on $E$.

Comment: This means that you probably want the smooth structure to satisfy some condition or another. For example, that the $s_i$ that you are given around each points be smooth sections of the bundle.

Comment: Ok, I want smooth sections (I should have been more careful writing, sorry)

Comment: In other words: your question should be: if I am given a map $\pi:E\to M$ defined on a *set* E such that each fiber is a vector space of dimension $k$, and for each point of $M$ I have $k$ sections of $\pi$ which span the fiber at each point of its domain, does $E$ have a smooth structure maiking $\pi$ a smooth vector bundle and such that the sections I had are smooth sections?

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Since smoothness is local, I could assume that the sections are defined in all of $M$, and try to put a structure on $E$ such that $E$ is a trivial bundle over $M$, with that structure making the sections smooth? If that's not it, then I'm completely lost now.

Comment: I don't think you can assume the sections are defined on all of $M$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean in your last comment, really.

Comment: Then why didn't you ask for a neighborhood $U$ and sections defined there such that yadda yadda yadda?

Comment: In your previous version, you mean? Because you did not impose any condition on the smooth structure other than that it turn $\pi$ into a vector bundle (in particular, you had no condition involving the sections): you could then just fix the trivial bundle $M\times R^k$, fir a bijection between $E_p$ and $R^k$, and put on your $E$ the unique smooth structure turning that into a diffeo.

Comment: No. When you tried to state my question in a better form you didn't mention a neighborhood of $p$. I'm assuming that every $p$ has a neighborhood $U$ and sections defined **only there** that span the fibers. You only said "and for each point of $M$ I have $k$ sections of $\pi$ which span...". Unless you meant that these $k$ sections are local in $p$?

Comment: Yes, of course, those sections were supposed to be local at $p$.

Comment: In any case: if $p$ is in $M$ and $U$ is the open set over which you have the $k$ local sections, then show that you can construct a smooth structure on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ turning that into a (trivial) bundle. Then you have to glue these "local" structures. I don't know if you can do that, as you imposed no compatibility between the local sections around one point and those around another.

Comment: I guess that would be the same that I want, no? The only thing left to do is to prove that the $h^i_{\hspace{.5em}j}$ are smooth. How do I do that? Then we apply lemma $5.5$ in Lee's book and done.

Comment: How do you do that? Well, as I wrote, I don´t think you can: you imposed no relation whatsoever between the local sections at one point and the local sections at another point.

Comment: (I am pretty sure that if you are trying to construct, say, quotient bundles, you can arrange for some compatibility between the local sections at different points so as to be able to prove the transition functions are smooth. But you obviously need something)

Comment: For example, in Morita's book he says to take a local frame $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ that spans $E$, such that $s_1,\cdots,s_\ell$ spans $F$, eventually shrinking the neighborhood of the initial point (so far, so good). Then $\overline{s_{\ell+1}},\ldots,\overline{s_{k}}$ span $E/F$, ok. This local frame in the quotient induces a trivialization, and we'd be done. But we don't know that $\bigsqcup_{p \in M}E_p/F_p$ is a manifold yet! So we can't talk about smoothness, and all of this isn't good for nothing...

Comment: As I said: in that case you *can* see that there is some form of compatibility between the local sections at different points that implies the transition functions are smooth. You **need** that. Write down what you need for the transition functions to be smooth and check that you can ensure that it holds.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm, then I'd have to compute the trivialization from the local frame and check directly that in that case everything glues correctly? Thanks for the patience.

Comment: I think that what Mariano is trying to say is that the "individualization" character of the definition of the local sections you gave cannot determine the global aspect of the bundle, which is of importance. For instance, by your definition, it seems you would be able to construct a Möebius band or a cylinder and know no difference.

Comment: I just saw that Mariano's edited his comment (and answered my last question). Your comment makes sense, thanks. I conclude that the equivalence between trivializations and local frames is only valid once we have a nice manifold structure on $E$ to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $S^1$, and $E_x=\mathbb{R}$ for every $x$. Now, consider the local "sections" $s_1:R\to E$ given by $s(x)=1_x$  for every $x$, and $s_2:L \to E$ given by $s(x)=1_x$ for every $x$, where $R$ and $L$ are the right and left part of the circle (slightly increased as to cover everything).

Those sections are smooth both when you pass to the Moebius band and to the cylinder. Therefore, the construction cannot yield an unique vector bundle structure. This is consonant to the fact that Mariano alludes to in the comments: the inexistence of a compatibility assumption of some sort in the sections. Note that in the Moebius band, the sections will twist "wrongly".

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the discussion in the comments: we can't prove smoothness of the $h^i_{\hspace{.5ex}j}$ - we don't have enough information. The equivalence between local trivializations and local frames only holds once $E$ already has a smooth manifold structure. In particular cases such as the quotient bundle, the idea seems to define sections, write the trivializations from them, and check that in the particular case everything glues correctly, and only then apply lemma $5.5$ of Lee's book.